# How exit from iPhone Full Screen of HTML 5 VIdeo player when video is done playing?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-events

I am using Cordova phonegap. I want to exit from full screen once video is ended. What should I use here?

Below is the code I use for video end detection:

```
$("#videoId").bind('ended',function(){
    // Full screen exit code here
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to use this one :

```
 $("#videoId")[0].webkitExitFullScreen();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: maybe makes sense to check for webkit: document.webkitExitFullscreen